# Back slash causing problems c++

Tags: c++, windows, path, escaping

I'm trying to use back slash in C++ in a string like this :

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "C:\Example\App.exe");
```

So for this example I would get these errors/warnings :"unknown escape sequence: '\E'" "unknown escape sequence: '\A'" .
Since I need to type in the exact name of the window , is there any way to avoid using back slashes or stop the compiler from interpreting them as "escape sequences" ?

Comment: I think you need another backslash to escape a backslash... In other words, to get a backslash, use '\\'

Comment: You can use front slash (`/`) in Windows paths just fine.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Except the code is trying to perform a string match against the title bar of a window.

Comment: Have a peek at raw string/character literals: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to escape them properly, C++11 added [raw string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) which eases this thing:

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, R"(C:\Example\App.exe)");
```

else do it manually:

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "C:\\Example\\App.exe");
```

Answer (score 4):

You should escape that properly:

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "C:\\Example\\App.exe");
```

For a full list of all escape sequences, check this:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape

Answer (score 1):

you can escape backslash doubling them:

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "C:\\Example\\App.exe");
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside a string literal a backslash is the first character of a character escape sequence. So `"\n"` consists of two characters: a newline character (from the `\n`) and a null character (because it's a string literal).

So, to get a backslash into the text, you need an escape character that represents a backslash. Simple enough: `"\\"` consists of two characters: a backslash character (from the `\\`) and a null character (because it's a string literal).

Another possibility is using a "raw string literal", which ignores escape sequences. `R"(\n\\)"` consists of five characters: a backslash character, an `n` character, two more backslash characters, and a null character (because it's a string literal).